# How can I globally include preact/hooks in my application and use it in my extension?

Tags: typescript, preact, microbundle

I am building an application in typescript/preact, which features extensions that can be installed on demand. I use preact globally, so that not every extension includes it as a dependency, but I am having problems with accessing *preact/hooks* from an extension.

Preact is included as a global via a script tag in the main index.html file:

```
<script src="/assets/js/vendor/preact.min.js"></script>
```

I use webpack to build my main application, where I use the *externals* attribute to indicate that preact is already available.

```
externals: {
  preact: 'preact',
}
```

Extensions are included in the application by reading a list from a JSON API, and then  dynamically loading their .js file, from which a global function will trigger a global function to register themselves.

I use *microbundle* to built the extension as a bundle file, where I indicate that preact is a global variable:

```
microbundle build --css external --globals preact=preact
```

So far, this works. The components are rendered properly, so no problems there. The problem is when I want to use the *useState* hook in a component. Normally in preact you import it by doing:

```
import { useState } from preact/hooks';
```

When I use load extension now, I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o is undefined
    <anonymous> remote-server-control.umd.js:1
    H index.js:525
    N index.js:206
    g children.js:143
    $ index.js:422
    N index.js:257
    g children.js:143
    $ index.js:422
    N index.js:257
    g children.js:143
    $ index.js:422
    N index.js:257
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    k component.js:128
    k component.js:218
    w component.js:206
    setState component.js:50
    __ Preact
    Redux 3
    P Preact
    Redux 4
    o utils.ts:11
    dispatch Redux
    C index.ts:223
    o utils.ts:8
    u Redux
    componentWillMount index.tsx:48
    N index.js:145
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    g children.js:143
    N index.js:223
    I render.js:36
    <anonymous> App.tsx:37
    async* index.ts:29
    Webpack 5
remote-server-control.umd.js:1:622
Source map error: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Resource URL: http://localhost:3192/extensions/remote-server-control/assets/remote-server-control.umd.js
Source Map URL: remote-server-control.umd.js.map
```

I've validated that when I disable the import of the useState hook, the problem does not occur. Since the import of preact/hooks is the only change I make, my feeling is that it is related to this, and this is where I am stuck. How can I make *preact/hooks* available globally for extensions to use, so code is not duplicated in each extension?

I've tried to add it to the globals flag in the microbuild command, but no success.

```
microbundle build --css external --globals preact=preact,preact/hooks=preact/hooks
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Unbywyd Yes, but it's not pretty. What I eventually did was:

In the module: `"build": "microbundle build --css external --globals preact=preact,preactHooks -o ../backend/build/web/microsoft-todo.js -f umd",`, and when I import the hooks I do: `import * from preactHooks;`

In the `index.html` of the general application I have this: `<script src="/assets/js/vendor/hooks.umd.js"></script>`, where `hooks.umd.js` is a copy of https://unpkg.com/browse/preact@10.5.14/hooks/dist/hooks.umd.js